# Wpf TreeView bound to list, how to get count

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

i'm trying to bind my TreeView to a List. But i can't get to show my bound list' count. Any help?

```
<TreeView x:Name="tree" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMyViewModels}">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}" >
          <!-- can navigate MyViewModel -->
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyViewModelProperty.Subproperty}" />

          <!-- CANNOT get ListOfMyViewModels Count -->
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" />
       </StackPanel>
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` does not specify `ItemsSource`. Does your `vm:MyViewModel` have `ListOfMyViewModels` property? At the moment it looks like flat list, not a tree

Comment: so with a flat list is not possible to show Count property?

Comment: So you want each item of the tree to show **same count** of how many item there are in the list? Because that's what will happen

Comment: try changing TextBlock DataContext, e.g.  <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ListOfMyViewModels}" Text="{Binding Path=Count}" />

Answer (score 0):

Changing DataContext solves the problem. Thanks to @Alex!

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ListOfMyViewModels}" Text="{Binding Path=Count}" />
```